# Lista em Python de números positivos e negativos

Tags: python

Como faço para que o **usuário digitar números positivos e negativos na mesma linha e a lista exibi-los em ordem do menor para o maior, de preferência que não use loop?**

```
Exemplo de números digitados
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5]

Exemplo de como a saída deve ser:
[-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Com o método `sort()`. Exemplo:

```
lista = []
i = 0
while i < 6:
    lista.append(int(input()))
    i += 1
lista.sort()
print(lista)
```

Para inverter a ordem é só fazer:

```
lista.sort(reverse = True)
```

sem o  while:

```
lista = []
lista.append(int(input()))
lista.append(int(input()))
lista.append(int(input()))
lista.append(int(input()))
lista.sort()
print(lista)
```

inserir todos os itens de uma vez:

```
lista = input().split()
lista.sort()
print(lista)
```

Nesse último caso a lista vai ser do tipo string pq o método split() só pode ser usado em strings, mas caso você precise que seja de outro tipo, basta converter depois. Lembrando que os valores devem estar separados por espaços.

Comment: Pra o usuário digitar os números positivos e negativos aleatoriamente onde a lista deve organiza-los do maior pro menor, o exemplo que fiz seria a saída do código

Comment: verdade, falta de atenção minha kkkkk, mas o método sort() vai ordenar de qualquer forma.

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: Como fica esse código sem usar *loop*? (para fins didáticos e entendimento)

Comment: a diferença é que você teria que colocar um lista.append(int(input())) pra cada item que você quiser adicionar na lista

Comment: Como é que insere todos os códigos na mesma linha?

Comment: editei na resposta, pra ficar melhor de ver

Comment: por quê tem tantos **lista.append(int(input()))?**

Comment: foi só pra ilustrar que precisa de um pra cada item que você quiser adicionar (no exemplo que você pediu ser usar looping)

Comment: Fala Alex, como a Laís explicou está certinho, porém ficaria sem lógica fazer esta operação sem loop. Pois assim seria um código muito ruim de escrever, a não ser que seja um requisito não usar nenhum tipo de loop, o que pra mim não faria sentido já que facilita e muito nossa vida como programador.

Comment: @LaísGodinho, você poderia fazer `lista = [ int(a) for a in input().split() ]` se não me engano. Daí você tem, novamente, os inteiros para brincar

Comment: `lista = input().split()
lista.sort()
print(lista)` está estranho ela mostra os resultados assim: **['-2', '-3', '-3', '-6', '1', '3', '4', '5']**, a parte de números negativos não fica na ordem como os números positivos